# Unable to locate binding.xml for Maven JAXB plugin (jaxb2-maven-plugin)

Tags: xml, maven, jaxb

this is my relevant part of pom.xml

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.6</version>
<executions>
 <execution>
    <id>xjc</id>
        <goals>
            <goal>xjc</goal>
        </goals>
         <configuration>
          <schemaDirectory>src/main/xsd</schemaDirectory>
           <schemaFiles>BILL.xsd</schemaFiles>
                       <bindingDirectory>src/main/java/xml</bindingDirectory>
                         <bindingFiles>binding.xml</bindingFiles>
                         <clearOutputDir>true</clearOutputDir>
                         <extension>true</extension>                               

              </configuration>
</execution>
</executions>
```

I am using jdk 1.7.
When running,its parsing the given xsd file and corresposding JAXB classes are being generated but my requirement is to generate separate classes, not inner ones as being currently generated.
For this, I have a very generic binding.xml

But on running jaxb2 plugin xjc; JAXB classes with inner static classes are being generated.
Any suggestions....
`

Comment: anyone need any clarifications?

Comment: Could you show us your xsd? .. i think that you use inner complex type.

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question. For me, it worked with version `0.14.0` of the `maven-jaxb2-plugin` by using the `<bindings>` configuration:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${jaxb2.maven.version}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <bindings>
            <binding>
                <fileset>
                    <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
                    <includes>
                        <include>binding.xml</include>
                    </includes>
                </fileset>
            </binding>
        </bindings>
    <configuration>
</plugin>
```

You can find the list of possible configurations on the [cheat sheet](https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin/wiki/Configuration-Cheat-Sheet).